# What is the benefit of having the back reference property in the foreign key table?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

In class Post, what is the benefit of specifying the optional property `public Blog Blog { get; set; }`?

```
public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Question of opinion. If you need back references it in querying data then they have benefit. Depends on each specific information requirement.

Comment: And a common reason to omit the Post.Blog Navigation property is so you don't have to manually exclude it from JSON serialization to avoid cycles.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Hmm, and why data entity model (which EF Core entity classes are) should care about serialization? These classes should not be used as DTOs anyway. Gert is right, this is highly opinionated.

Comment: I only mention it because OP was previously asking about building an web API, and hitting serialization cycles in a common issue.  And IMO "what are the benefits/risks/downsides" of a design decision is a valid question, even if people have different opinions about how do make that decision.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I agree that it's a valid question, by all means! It's just not a good fit on Stack Overflow. A question like: is it beneficial in this specific case? would make a better chance of being on-topic. The only thing is, I think that any specific case reduces the question to a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: It is all about the community. When you understand someone is lost, the community helps. Where as what has happened here is policing. Just drives beginner away from the technology/community. And by community I mean both stack Overflow as well as .net community. Personal opinion.

Comment: Questions are on-topic or not. Stack Overflow has pretty strict guidelines on that, for very good reasons. Doesn't say anything about how *valid* questions are.  I'd love to discuss this topic for as long as it takes. Just not here.

Answer (score 2):

the main benefit is that you can use Include instead of explicitly joining tables

```
var posts=context.Posts.Include(i=>i.Blog).ToList();
```

Comment: Is the following line optional for your query to work `public int BlogId { get; set; }`?

Comment: @variable Blog is optional only, but BlogId is not optional. It should be a column of database table. Otherwise nothing will be working properly. You can not  have Blog as a  relational database column,  since it is a complex object with many properties.

Comment: But Blog class already has Posts. Isn't only that enough for EF to understand the relationship.

Comment: And as I understand you are saying that BlogId is optional but `public Blog Blog { get; set; }` is a must. I get your point.

Comment: You can' not save list of Posts in a  database column too. List is created in the memory during dbcontext initiation, using BlogId forensic key. Without this key Posts can not be created too.

Comment: I am saying BlogId is a must, since you need it  to save relations. Blog is optional and can not be created  if you  don't have a BlogId.

Comment: The truth is that neither `Blog.Posts` nor `Post.Blog` nor `Post.BlogId` **property** is required in the entity classes (as usual @Serge is mixing class with database table). But they are good to have, especially navigation properties.

Comment: I get your point now that the collections only allow ef to link the tables. Where as the non collections are compulsory for the database. Without collections we won't be able to reference in the c# code.

Comment: @variable Some novice develpers create onlya  Blog property. But  EF creates BlogId  column for them behind the scene.

Comment: @ivan - isn't either of Blog.Posts or Post.Blog required required ef to understand the relationship.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi, nice to see you again. I am wondering how I can keep relations between Post and Blog without BlogId or without the third table with BlogId and PostId

Comment: May I request you update the answer with the minimum code (by removing the parts from my code that are not required) for your query to work.

Comment: @variable If you mean to "understand" it **automatically**, yes. But in general no - one can use fluent API to configure relationship with 0, 1 or 2 **navigation** properties and explicit / **shadow** FK property. Al this is in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

Comment: @variable Requiered is not the best word here. It depends on do you need to link blog and post or  you can keep them independantly. and what kind relations to you need one-one, one-many, many-many. if one=one you can live without BlogId too.

Comment: This link says that 1 navigation property is enough - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property - @serge - will your code work with such sample.

Comment: I need 1:M between blog and posts in that example.

Comment: @IvanStoev  As I undestand you mean not normilized data, when you told that it doesn't need BlogId?

Comment: @Serge I didn't say the **table** won't have `BlogId` FK **column**. See again - I'm highlighting the words **class** and **property**. EF is OR **Mapper**, so class properties are not required to be exactly as the database table columns.

Comment: Also you can write queries like `context.Posts.Where(p=>p.Blog.Name == "Foo")`

Answer (score 1):

It is a bi-directional reference. Generally my advice around them is only use them when there is a distinct need for them. If relationships between entities can change (for instance if a post could be moved between blogs) then making that change from one side of the relationship would not be reflected on the other side until after `SaveChanges` is called unless you explicitly updated both sides.

Typically in a system you identify aggregate roots for the entity relationships, and you can query all entities through those roots. At the end of the day do you expect that you'd ever have code that gets given a Post entity that ever needs to work out what Blog it was associated with? If so, a bi-directional reference has value.

Comment: Please can you point me to documentation that will help me get my understanding around this? Its very confusing to decide when to add what field so as to establish the link.

Comment: A good place to start is understanding EF configuration. For EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/. I recommend getting familiar with both annotation-based config and "grouping" configuration using `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. EF can work out a lot of things by convention so many examples and simple mappings just work, but learning the configuration methods will help you understand what's happening behind the scenes and set up relationships without EF doing something "odd". As for when, it's a question of "will I get a B and need to get to A through it?"

Comment: @variable You should show your own code. In this example it's impossible to decide whether *any* property is justified, because there's no code actually using the model. As I said above, in actual code the answer to this question will always be an obvious yes/no.

Comment: @GertArnold - I have given the model classes. What else do you mean by actual code please?

Comment: The code you show here is from the EF examples. I assume you're currently writing code using EF yourself. It would be much easier to answer question about code you write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object of the class `Post`, it knows which blog it belongs to. If this property is not set, you would need to search all the posts in all the blogs, if you want to find that out.